# javascript: изменить поле в объекте массива одной строкой

Tags: javascript, массивы, поиск, setstate

есть массив объектов (ассоциативных массивов):

```
data = [
    {
        name: 'obj1',
        value: data1
    },
    {
        name: 'obj2',
        value: data2
    },
]
```

можно ли в 1 строку заменить значение `value` в объекте с заданным `name` и вернуть измененный массив?

это для изменения состояний через setState в компоненте React нужно

можно конечно все в несколько строчек сделать через создание временного объекта

```
const tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));

const index = this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name));
tmp[index]['value'] = newValue;

setState({
    data: tmp
});
```

но хотелось бы в 1 строку, чтоб не писать лишнего кода

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно получить новый массив иначе React не отрисует изменения, и у Вас появится дополнительный вопрос почему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` может принимать как объект так и функцию, по Вашему коду правда не понятно хук это или нет (похоже что нет), но насколько я помню с хуками так же. Я бы не гнался за краткостью в угоду читабельности

```
setState((oldState) =>  {
    const index = oldState.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name);
    oldState.data.splice(index, 1, {...oldState.data[index], value: newValue }) 
    return { data: Array.from(oldState.data)}
});
```

Теоретически это можно записать так (но я бы не стал):

```
this.state.data.splice(this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name), 1, {...this.state.data[this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name)], value: newValue}) 

setState({
   data: Array.from(this.state.data)
});
```

`splice` преобразовывает массив по месту и возвращает удаленные элементы поэтому его нельзя куда-то засунуть, он должен быть отдельной строкой.

**Обновление**

Я все таки смог извратиться и засунуть все в одну строку, но оно Вам надо?) Основной смысл вырезать до индекса и после и втиснуть между измененный элемент:

```
setState({data:  Array.from([...this.state.data.slice(0, this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name)), {...this.state.data[this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name)], value: newValue}, ...this.state.data.slice(this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.name === name) +1, this.state.data.length)])})
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно воспользоваться методом [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) который сразу возвращает **новый** массив.

```
setState({
    data: this.state.data.map(el => el.name === name ? {...el, value: newValue} : el)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

как вариант нормалное решение

```
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    {
      name: 'obj1',
      value: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'obj2',
      value: 2,
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const name = 'obj2';
    setState((prev) => {
      const { foundObj, filteredArr } = prev.reduce(
        (acc: { foundObj; filteredArr }, next) => {
          if (next.name === name) {
            acc.foundObj = { ...next };
          } else {
            acc.filteredArr.push(next);
          }
          return acc;
        },
        { foundObj = {}, filteredArr: [] },
      );
      return [
        ...filteredArr,
        {
          ...foundObj,
          value: 3333,
        },
      ];
    });
  }, []);
```

в одну строку

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const name = 'obj2';
    // const reg = new RegExp(String.raw`{("name":${name}, "value")\w+}`);
    // setState((prev) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prev).replace(reg, '$1:3333')));

    const reg = new RegExp(String.raw`{(\w+:${name}\w+(?=:))\w+}`);
    setState((prev) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prev).replace(reg, '$1:3333')));
  }, []);
```